# basic calculator created in javascript.. use an alert to tell user about any errors. the possible errors include:

Tags: javascript

I've created a basic 4 function calculator in JavaScript and now I need to use an alert to tell the user about any errors. the possible errors are:

1. One or both input fields are blank
2. One or both input fields < -9999 or greater than 9999
3. Divide by zero
4. Illegal character in either input field. Only 0, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9, and – are allowed.

Code:

```js
function multiplyBy() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}

function divideBy() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
}

function additionBy() {
  num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
  num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber").value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 + num2;
}

function subtractionBy() {
  num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
  num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber").value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 - num2;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <form>
    1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber"> 2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber"> The Result is :
    <span id="result"></span>
    <br>
    </br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Multiply" />
    <input type="button" onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
    <input type="button" onClick="additionBy()" Value="Add" />
    <input type="button" onClick="subtractionBy()" Value="Sub" />
    </br>
  </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fourth.js">
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read the help section on asking questions then edit your question.  This will help the community give you a better answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show how you attach those function to your HTML and provide that HTML.

Comment: i added my JS and HTML code i have come up with so far

Comment: I made a snippet of the code, however I did NOT fix the malformed markup in the HTML

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 1):

first of all define the input tag type as number like below

```
1st Number : <input type="number" id="firstNumber" >
2nd Number: <input type="number" id="secondNumber" >
```

so, in that case user will not be able to enter invalid input.

secondly, check the divide by zero condition into the function only

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a validation pattern.

To check if the inputs are valid you can perform checks at the beginning of your math functions. For example

```
var $num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
var $num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber");
var $result = document.getElementById("result");

function checkValid(division){
  var num1 = $num1.value;
  var num2 = $num2.value;

  if(num1 == null || num1 > 9999 || num1 < -9999){
    return false;
  }

  if(num2 == null || num2 > 9999 || num2 < -9999){
    return false;
  }

  if(division && num2 === 0){
    return false
  }
}

function multiplyBy() {
  if(check()){
    num1 = $num1.value;
    num2 = $num2.value;
    $result.innerHTML = num1 * num2;
  } else {
    alert('some error message');
  }
}
```

then in your division function call `check(true)`

This is just one way to handle it. You could call alert in the check function before returning or even return your error messages from the check function. This should get going in the right direction.

Also I do recommend the `<input type="number">` changes by Hasan as well.

Comment: does this go into my js file in replace of anything i currently have? or is it in addition to what i already have?

Comment: please help. i am not sure if i need to erase what i have put in my js file above completley or just add the var $num1 = etc. code that SnareChops provided above. im stuck :(

Comment: The `var $num1 = etc` stuff is just another way you could be shortening your code instead of duplicating the `document.getElementById("...")` everywhere. The `multiplyBy()` function is a replacement of your current function, and the `check()` function is new

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries for validation that you can get but lets start simple.  Rework what you have to remove duplicated code and then add functions to do your validation.

This is JUST A START not a complete solution, you have to do work.  I will leave it to you to add the OTHER validation you need, but you can see how this is doing it with the couple I added.

```js
function showResults(results) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = results;
}

function multiplyBy(number1, number2) {
  num1 = number1.value;
  num2 = number2.value;
  showResults(num1 * num2);
}

function divideBy(number1, number2) {
  num1 = number1.value;
  num2 = number2.value;
  showResults(num1 / num2);
}

function additionBy(number1, number2) {
  num1 = parseInt(number1.value, 10);
  num2 = parseInt(number2.value, 10);
  showResults(num1 + num2);
}

function subtractionBy(number1, number2) {
  num1 = parseInt(number1.value, 10);
  num2 = parseInt(number2.value, 10);
  showResults(num1 - num2);
}

function actionClicker() {
  let number1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
  let number2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber");
  validateNumber(number1);
  validateNumber(number2);
  var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
  var expr = attribute;
  switch (expr) {
    case 'multiply':
      multiplyBy(number1, number2);
      break;
    case 'division':
      divideBy(number1, number2);
      break;
    case 'subtract':
      subtractionBy(number1, number2);
      break;
    case 'addition':
      additionBy(number1, number2);
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Sorry, we do not find ' + expr + '.');
  }
}

function showValidationMessage(message) {
  alert(message);
}

function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function isEmpty(n) {
  return n === "";
}

function isInRange(n) {
  if (isNumeric(n) && !isEmpty(n)) {
    num = parseInt(n, 10);
    return num >= -9999 && num <= 9999;
  }
  return false;
}

function validateNumber(el) {
  let hasError = false;
  el.classList.remove("has-error");
  // add your validation
  let message = "get stuff better";
  if (!isNumeric(el.value)) {
    message = "Not a number.";
    hasError = true;
  }
  if (isEmpty(el.value)) {
    message = "Not a number, cannot be empty.";
    hasError = true;
  }
  if (hasError) {
    el.classList.add("has-error");
    showValidationMessage(message);
  }
}

function modifyNumbers(event) {
  let el = event.target;
  validateNumber(el);
}
var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber");
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('actions');
// add event listener to buttons
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', actionClicker, false);
}
num1.addEventListener("change", modifyNumbers, false);
num2.addEventListener("change", modifyNumbers, false);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 2em;
}

label {
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em
}

.has-error {
  background-color: lightpink;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.numbers {
  width: 11em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="firstNumber">1st Number:</label><input class="numbers" type="number" id="firstNumber" placeholder="Min: -9999, max: 9999" min="-9999" max="9999" /><span class="validity"></span><label for="secondNumber">2nd Number:</label><input class="numbers"
      type="number" id="secondNumber" placeholder="Min: -9999, max: 9999" min="-9999" max="9999" /><span class="validity"></span>
    <div><label>The Result is:</label>
      <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button type="button" class="actions" id="multiply" data-myattribute="multiply">Multiply</button>
      <button type="button" class="actions" id="divide" data-myattribute="division">Divide</button>
      <button type="button" class="actions" id="add" data-myattribute="addition">Add</button>
      <button type="button" class="actions" id="subtract" data-myattribute="subtract">Sub</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```